# Where is "Align at =" feauture to align equations in Word 2019?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, equation-editor, microsoft-office-2019, microsoft-word-2019

I have three equations in MS Word 2019, I want to align them at the equal sign. I found [this advice](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/aligning-equal-signs-for-continuing-an-equation/13ac3808-4df9-43cb-8330-49a9c6c02f04) (also [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-word-equations-align-at-only-working-if/74b84614-0529-483b-ac3d-8c59f5308669)):

> Type the first two equations in separate equation containers, just as
> you show them here. Then select both lines, right-click anywhere in
> the selected area, and choose "Align at =".

I follow this in MS Word 2019, but I cannot find anything close to "Align at =":

[image]

**Is this feature available in MS Word 2019? Where?**

Answer (score 1):

`Align at =` option won't appear as your second and third equation are separated by a paragraph. Remove the paragraph, select the equations, rigth-click and you will see the option `Align at =`

**Equations separated by a paragraph**

[image]

**Equations without a paragraph**

[image]